# How to execute angular function on page load?

Tags: angularjs

Some issue with this code, filltable() function is not firing during page load.
I have done the back end in webservice.

```js
  
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
         $scope.fillTable();
        $scope.fillTable = function () {
            $scope.Name= "";
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:61292/PPAPI.asmx/GetTables',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: {}
            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {
                $scope.TableList= response.d;
            })
        };
        $scope.fillTable ();
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: in the html do you include ng-controller ?

Comment: yes I do.
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl"  ></div>

Comment: On what basis are you determining that that fill table doesn't execute? It actually should run twice based on the code you posted.

Comment: @manuvijay could you share your html. or edit the snipped with the html. cause if you are doing like you say the function fill must execute.

Answer (score 0):

LT56 answer works, but it's deprecated to initialize data with `ng-init`.

From `AngularJS Documentation` :

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

I recommend you to use an `init` function that you will call at the end of your JS file as you're already doing.

Concerning your issue, it should be working. Please check if your console developer displays any error. You may forgot to include your `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine based on your code. Some typos are there which i fixed in the below code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.fillTable = function() {
            console.log("call");
        };
        $scope.fillTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using angular version 1.2, Use [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) function to execute your intialiation code.  With version 1.6, just create a function call $onInit() inside your controller.

```
<myControl ng-init="fillTable()"></myControl>
```

Comment: ng-init is only to be used as a last resort.

Comment: @MikeFeltman indeed it seems better to use controller instead of `ng-init `